# Flask Error extending html with template: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: tag name expected

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I am doing a basic flask html extension and I have no idea why it is throwing an error. Here is my code:

[image: python code]

[image: index html]

[image: base html]

What syntax error am I missing?

Comment: Several recommendations: 1. If you want SO users to reproduce your problem, you may want to post the entire project, and not just screenshots of your editor. 2. A complete stack trace of your error message may give a more complete picture of your problem. 3. Any of [these topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) may guide you in writing a question useful for the whole community.

Answer (score 1):

In your `base.html`, it should be `{% extends "base.html" %}`, not `{% {% extends base.html %} %}`.

Remove that and you are good to go.

EDIT:

Also, to keep content from `base.html`, use `{{ super() }}` as a first line in `blocks`.

For example:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {{ super() }} {# to keep yours h1 tag #}
    ...Additional content to add
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dinko is correct. Next time, try use Debug=True and post the output here. It's help to find a error.

See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/templateinheritance/ to more information about Templates.

Comment: Yes, debug logs are good when having an error. Also to you, welcome to stack overflow :)